# Inverse of infinitely differentiable function

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $U\subset R^n$ be an open set. Let $f:U\to R^n$ be smooth. That is, all the components of $f$ are $C^\infty(U)$. Suppose there exists $q\in U$ and $\det(D_qf)\neq 0$. Then by inverse function theorem, there exists $V\subset U$ open such that $f:V\to f(V)$ is a bijection and $f^{-1}:f(V)\to V$ is $C^1(f(V))$. How do I show that $f^{-1}$ is in fact $C^\infty (f(V))$?

The inverse function theorem tells us the first order derivative of $f^{-1}$ at $f(p)$ is $[D_{f(p)}f^{-1}]=[D_pf]^{-1}$ and that it is continuous. To show second order derivative exists, I would need to differentiate $[D_{f(p)}f^{-1}]$ with respect to $f(p)$. I'm very confused here. Is $\frac{df^{-1}}{dq}=D_qf^{-1}$ a function from $f(V)$ to $n*n$ matrices? How do I show this is differentiable?

Comment: I think it follows by the chain rule and induction on the degree of the derivative.

Comment: @Matematleta Can you be more specific? What do I use chain rule to?

Comment: Sure. See my answer, I sketched the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the inverse function theorem, $Df^{-1}(f(x))=(Df(x))^{-1}.$ Define the $C^{\infty}$ map $\Phi:\mathscr L_I(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n)\to \mathscr L  (\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n):T\to T^{-1}.$  Then,

$Df^{-1}(f(x))=(\Phi\circ Df)(x)$ or, with $y=f(x)$,

$Df^{-1}(y)=(\Phi\circ Df\circ f^{-1})(y).$

Apply the chain rule to the right hand side of this to show that $Df^{-1}$ is itself differentiable. Now consider $DDf^{-1}$ The same reasoning proves that it is differentiable.

You can formalize this easily to prove the claim by induction.